# Move .price-box in view.phtml

Tags: layout, frontend, product-view

I would like to display my product's price directly under its name.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Err, by doing exactly what your title states, move `.price-box` (`$this->getPriceHtml($_product);`) to where you so wish in the `view.phtml` template file. If below product name, then `$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')`.

Comment: @zigojacko please add this as an answer and tell me, then I'll delete mine

Answer (score 4):

move

```
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

to where you so wish in the `view.phtml` template file. If below product name, then after `$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')`